# Is a sentence, composed of mainclause and subclause, represented by one or two syntax-trees?

Tags: syntax, grammar, syntax-trees

I read, that

- one sentence can have different syntax-trees
- what is considered a phrase is dependent on the grammar used
- there are a lot of grammars, basically divided into two groups: phrase-structure grammars and dependency grammars

This focus on context creates for me the problem to find out, how sentences which are made of a main clause and subclause are represented by a syntax tree or maybe two ?

problematic sentences (e.g.):

- I like turtles, because I like green animals.
- I like turtles and I like turkeys.
- I like turtles, because I like green stuff, because green symbolizes luck.

Comment: Typically it's represented by a branching syntax tree, mathematically equivalent to parentheses (but taking up more room on the page) See the [Logic Study Guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) and the [Verb Phrase Study Guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf) for more specific examples.

Answer (score -2):

This could very well be explained in a difficult way, but it may also be that you are seeking an easy answer.

Basically you could say;
*One clause=one syntax tree*

If a sentence consists of several clauses, you could draw several syntax trees.

Comment: Please give some examples of this. I am struggling to picture how one sentence could be effectively shown by multiple syntax trees.

Comment: Nonsense! Nonsense!